# What is the rule to write furigana (ruby)?

Tags: furigana

I am confused in determining the correct way to write furigana.

1. Is a furigana only allowed to be attached to a single kanji character? In other words, can a furigana attached to more than one kanji character? If a furigana can only be attached to a single kanji, how to write furiganas for, e.g., 今日?
2. Where should the　`っ` which is the small つ be positioned in furiganas for words, e.g., 一緒? Which one is the correct one?  一{い}  緒{っしょ}　or  一{いっ} 緒{しょ}?
3. Is it correct to write　居{い}所{どころ}　instead of 居{い}所{ところ}?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're taking care to write the readings over the characters they belong to (which people don't always do), then geminated consonants belong to the first kanji:

> **学{がく}** + 校{こう} ***gaku** + kō*　　＝　　**学{がっ}**校{こう} ***gak**kō*

As you can see, the consonant still belongs to the first kanji.  ***Gak*** is a reduced form of ***gaku***, having lost its final vowel **u**.  Likewise, in your example you would split **一**緒 into **いっ** and しょ.

Sometimes readings are assigned to entire compounds rather than to individual kanji.  Although **今**日 was historically compositional (***ke*** + pu), these days it's treated as a 熟字訓 reading—a reading assigned to an entire compound, rather than made up of the individual readings normally associated with those characters.  So in cases like these, it makes more sense not to try to split them up:

> **今日{きょう}** ***kyō***

In your last example, **ど**ころ ***d**okoro* is a [rendaku](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rendaku)'ed form of **と**ころ ***t**okoro*.  Just like with our earlier examples of **がっ** ***gak*** and **いっ** ***is***, we'll write it the way it's pronounced, rather than trying to represent an "underlying" pronunciation with the /t/ intact:

> 居{い} + **所{ところ}** *i* + ***tokoro***　　＝　　居{い}**所{どころ}** *i**dokoro***

Generally, you should write furigana with the standard pronunciation of the word you're writing, unless you're trying to specifically emphasize another pronunciation.  Since Japanese spelling was reformed recently and is now relatively accurate, that makes things fairly simple.

You'll find that there are people who pronounce a few words differently than they're spelled.  Normally, you would write:

> **女王{じょおう}・体育{たいいく}・雰囲気{ふんいき}**　rather than　**女王{じょうおう}・体育{たいく}・雰囲気{ふいんき}**

In these cases, I think it's better to write them like the left—unless you're trying to specifically indicate that you pronounce them like on the right.

Comment: Is it common to use furigana in hand writing in addition to typing?

Comment: Splitting them up doesn't always work, even when one tries hard: 海鷂魚【えい】.

Comment: FWIW, I'm used to hearing たいいく (with four morae) and ふんいき (with the ん before the い). Not sure about 女王, but then that hasn't come up as often in conversation.

Comment: Sure, those are the standard pronunciations.  But it's not hard to find people who pronounce them the other way.

Answer (score 4):

I'm just addressing #1, since snailboat covered the other ones very well.

> Is a furigana only allowed to be attached to a single kanji character?

No. In fact, it's common to attach furigana to a kanji compound, as seen in

- [Matcha (やさしい日本語 version)](http://mcha-easy.com/)
- [NHK Web Easy](http://www3.nhk.or.jp/news/easy/index.html)
- [City of Tsukuba's site (やさしい日本語 version)](http://www.tsukubainfo.jp/jp/)

There are also some that attach furigana to single kanji

- [Hiragana Times](http://www.hiraganatimes.com/ja/). Here's a screenshot

  [image]
- [Asagaku](http://www.asagaku.com/) (Asahi Shimbun's newspapers for students - [PDF samples here](http://www.asagaku.com/shidoku.html))
- Manga (not sure if this applies to all manga with furigana though). Here's a screenshot

  [image]

Some sites use both (furigana on single kanji and furigana on kanji compounds), like [kids goo.ne.jp](http://kids.goo.ne.jp/)

I think which one is used ultimately depends on ratio of kanji font size to hiragana font size. If the ratio is large enough, then furigana is applied to single kanji.

---

p/s: Hmmm, screenshots might be too large...